# TeamCity + Psake + SqlCmd Powershell infinite loop

Tags: teamcity, sqlcmd, psake

I'm trying to use the Powershell Runner in TeamCity 6.5.2 to run a Psake task that depends on a task that calls out to SqlCmd.  If I try to do this, teamcity seems to get into an infinite loop until it eventually times out or errors out.

I'm usinged the -Command option in TeamCity otherwise errors to don't bubble to TeamCity.

It seems like it has something to do with SqlCmd.  I found this [blog](http://blog.cincura.net/232312-teamcity-powershell-and-sqlcmd-problem-and-solution/#comment-6039) and tried tweaking the sqlcmd encoding to Unicode but no luck.

Has anyone else seen this behavior and if so how to fix?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today.

The bug is [TW-17732 in their YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-17732) it's a bug in the `-Command` mode of the runner and they are deprecating it instead of solving it.

The recommended mode is the `-File` mode but it might require you to change the security policy on each agent by typing in an Administrator powershell console:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Answer (score 0):

One place where I have seen PSake causing hang is regarding log output. Can you try redirecting the output of the sqlcmd to nul (`>nul`) and se e? Or use `out-null` or whatever is appropriate.